# Select item id by item name

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I get all Brushes colors

```
var colorNames = typeof(Brushes)
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Select(x => x.Name);
```

How can I get color index where color name is "Black"?

Why I can't go this way `colorNames.FirstOrDefault(color => color.Name == "Black").Id;`?

Edit: I use `colorNames` for DropDown data, I need index of certain color to set it as default DropDown value.

Comment: What do you want, exactly? What property do you need?

Comment: I need index which corresponds to item with certain name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to return the index of the color that is Black, use this query:

```
var colors = typeof(Brushes)
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                .ToList();

var index = colors.FindIndex(color => color.Name == "Black");
```

After testing this, I get the value of `8` for the index of the color which is Black

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found